# Is there a memory leak in Cocoa framework? Or am I missing something?

Tags: xcode, macos, memory-leaks

1. In order to reproduce this problem simply create a Cocoa App, choose
   either Swift or Objective-C (i have tested both) Run the project.
2. Open the `debug navigator`(your app's initial memory consumption
   should be around 25MB), simply play around with your empty app's
   drop down menus, and observe the memory consumption to grow significantly in a short period of time.
3. Then from `Open Developer Tool` in Xcode open `Instruments`, In the
   `Choose a profiling template` choose `Leaks` and choose your app as
   the target, and then click the record button.
4. Now simply play with your app, resize the window, open up drop down
   menus. After a few minutes you will notice memory consumption will
   rise up above 110MB and you will notice leak points, if you click
5. The memory leak from your app will continue to grow until your system runs out of memory.
6. Pause and then click on the detected leak spots (red crosses on the time line), you will probably see some of the culprits below:

The list is too long so I only include a few, but all of them are from AppKit without exception:

```
_NSLocalEventObserver   1   0x60000023ab00  32 Bytes    AppKit  +  [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:placement:handler:]
_NSViewAuxiliary    1   0x110107080 448 Bytes   AppKit  -[NSView(NSInternal) _allocAuxiliary:]
NSPopUpButtonCell   1   0x6080001c7530  240 Bytes   AppKit  -[NSControl initWithFrame:]
NSControlAuxiliary  1   0x60800024c840  48 Bytes    AppKit  -[NSControl _commonEarlyInit]
NSMutableDictionary 1   0x60800024c6c0  48 Bytes    AppKit  -[NSCell setFont:]
NSPopUpButton   1   0x60800036e940  192 Bytes   AppKit  -[NSSpellChecker init]
NSCellAuxiliary 1   0x6080000eb280  128 Bytes   AppKit  -[NSCell init]
Malloc 48 Bytes 1   0x60800024c6f0  48 Bytes    AppKit  -[NSCell setFont:]
NSMenu  1   0x608000861f40  64 Bytes    AppKit  -[NSPopUpButtonCell initTextCell:pullsDown:]
_NSMenuImpl 1   0x6080000cdc10  112 Bytes   AppKit  -[NSMenu _createExtraIvars]
NSCarbonMenuImpl    1   0x6080000cdc80  112 Bytes   AppKit  -[NSMenu _createMenuImpl]
NSExtraMICData  1   0x608000038c00  32 Bytes    AppKit  -[NSMenuItemCell initTextCell:]
NSMutableArray  1   0x60800024daa0  48 Bytes    AppKit  -[NSMenu insertItem:atIndex:]
```

Is this a known bug? I haven't touched the code generated by Xcode. Is there a memory leak in AppKit or Cocoa framework or possibly both? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The memory size will grow due to (4) – objects like menus may not get allocated until first used, etc. – however such growth will not be unbounded.

Unable to reproduce your results: running under 10.13.2 & Xcode 9.2 no unbounded growth was seen and no leaks reported.

That is not to say you are not seeing it, just that the cause is unknown but unlikely to be a "leak" in the frameworks *per se*. Try another machine, check your setup, etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and actually trying this, to see if there really is a problem.

Comment: Buy the way after all objects got allocated memory consumption shouldn't go up above a certain point, which in this case does.